# Failed to resolve Twitter SDK

Tags: android, maven, android-studio, gradle

I am getting this error while building the android project :

```
Error:Failed to resolve: com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter:2.0.0
```

This is my gradle file :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion '22.0.1'

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.khurana.nikhil.tuhub"
    minSdkVersion 17
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    manifestPlaceholders = [manifestApplicationId          : "${applicationId}",
                            onesignal_app_id               : "3363b4de-b4d3-45c7-a74a-2d75d7a97848",
                            onesignal_google_project_number: "561678063868"]
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE-FIREBASE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.+'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.1'
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.0.0'
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:1.0.0'
compile 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:2.+@aar'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:10.0.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:10.0.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:10.0.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.0.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.0.0'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

I tried this solution mentioned in one of the post but that didn't work. Here's the solution  I found :
Adding this to project gradle Repository section

```
maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/repo' }
```

But this didn't work.
Tried this too :`maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/repo' }`

Comment: https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/issues/392

Comment: Thanks mate. I had already visited that link but failed to notice that repository line has to been added in app gradle file as well. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

Adding the repository worked for me. Here's my build gradle(project)

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2'

        // Google Play Services classpath
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Hope this helps :)